# Query Buscar Palavra Específica em um Campo - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Existe alguma função que eu consiga buscar somente o dado de um campo ?

Estou tentando buscar somente da Validade até 2019, tenho várias linhas com essa informação de validade, e elas não aparecem na mesma posição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sempre existirá o texto "validade" na coluna DescricaoAndamento? A data sempre está no formato dd/mm/aaaa ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *Estou tentando buscar somente da Validade até 2019*

Experimente algo como

```
-- código #1 v3
...
case when charindex (', validade ', DescricaoAndamento) > 0
          then substring (DescricaoAndamento, 
                          charindex (', validade ', DescricaoAndamento) +2, 
                          19)
     else NULL end
...
```

O trecho de código acima inicialmente procura onde inicia o texto ", validade ".

Foi considerado que a data de validade sempre conterá 10 caracteres.